# Invalid key length while trying to encrypt file using node crypto/cipher

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, cryptography

I am facing issue in making a encrypter in node.js by using inbuilt crypto package.

- My code -

```
async function encryptFile(inputFile, key = "1234") {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (key == "1234") {
            return reject("Set a good key");
        }
        fs.stat(inputFile, function (err) {
            if (err)
                return reject("No such file");
            if (inputFile.endsWith(".enc"))
                return resolve("Already Encrypted");
            encryptFileI(inputFile, pathModule.dirname(inputFile) + "/" + encryptText(pathModule.basename(inputFile), key) + ".enc", key, function (err) {
                if (err)
                    return reject(err);
                else
                    fs.unlink(inputFile, function (err) {
                        if (err)
                            return reject();
                        else
                            return resolve();
                    });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

- Error I am facing -

```
internal/crypto/cipher.js:103
    this[kHandle].initiv(cipher, credential, iv, authTagLength);
                  ^

Error: Invalid key length
    at Cipheriv.createCipherBase (internal/crypto/cipher.js:103:19)
    at Cipheriv.createCipherWithIV (internal/crypto/cipher.js:121:20)
    at new Cipheriv (internal/crypto/cipher.js:227:22)
    at Object.createCipheriv (crypto.js:123:10)
    at encryptFileI (C:\Users\jhama\Desktop\Node-encrypter\index.js:74:25)
    at C:\Users\jhama\Desktop\Node-encrypter\index.js:118:13
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:182:5)
```

> encryptFile function works when I run it another function.

- It works in the code below but not standalone

```
async function encryptFolder(path, key, maxFileSize = 0) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        key = Buffer.from(key.split('').reverse().join('')).toString('base64');
        key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(key, Buffer.from('ba6dfaa9a6db69f0f2d50745a3516f1cb080e637ceadea4f5e6d9edff3c079602130694585e1df1a3a3176b20fcd10b0af87f6dc766fafd26b0928e7c49ebcdf', 'hex'), 2145, 32, 'sha512');
        var files = await recursive(path, ["node_modules", "*.enc"]);
        var promises = []
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            if (maxFileSize != 0)
                if (((fs.statSync(file).size) / 1000000.0) > maxFileSize)
                    continue
            promises.push(encryptFile(file, key));
        }
        Promise.all(promises).then(() => { resolve() }).catch((err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

---

If anyone could help with this it would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Github link - https://github.com/AdityaXJha/AES-256-encrypter

Comment: Your code is incomplete and we are not been able to run it, e.g. the encryptFileI function is missing. Kindly edit your question and add a minimal but full running program, eventuell if it runs into the described error, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I added the github link with whole source code. Hope that helps.

Comment: Please do not post a link, but an executable example that can be used to reproduce the issue and that should be _as short as possible_. Take a look at the post [_How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Topaco Minimal reproducible wont work as it uses other packages too as node modules.

Comment: _User-defined_ modules must be posted, of course, if they are required for a repro. You have to try out what all is needed to reproduce your issue and not leave it to the community. Looking at the code, I can't imagine that everything is necessary for a repro. And if it is, you need to post that code. A link alone is insufficient. If the link is dead at some point, the problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @Topaco I already posted the code which doesn't work actually and the code which works but it wont directly run in minimal reproducible example as its node js.